# Want to direct user to their account after sign up

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, header

just creating a simple signup form, and want my users after they've signed up to be direct to their account page. however im having problems as the information will get stored in the database but the page will not get directed.

```
<?php
session_start();
include "php/config/database.php";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $Surname   = $_POST['Surname'];
    $Email     = $_POST['Email'];
    $Password  = $_POST['Password'];

    // Check if data exists already in the database

    $exists  = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Email FROM Users WHERE Email = '$Email'");
    $row     = mysqli_fetch_array($exists);
    $dbEmail = $row['Email'];
    if ($Email == $dbEmail) {
        die("Email already taken.");
    }
}

$registerUser = "INSERT INTO Users(FirstName,Surname,Email,Password)VALUES('$FirstName','$Surname','$Email','$Password')"; { // Select ID from registered user
    $selectID           = "SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE Email = '$Email'";
    $selectID_Query     = mysqli_query($conn, $selectID);
    $fetch              = mysqli_fetch_array($selectID_Query);
    $userID = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    $userID             = $fetch['UserID'];
    $_SESSION['UserID'] = $UserID;
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $registerUser)) {
        header("Location: account.php");
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('error while registering you...');</script>";
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>background</title>
 </head>
  <body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php  - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Your register_user query is failing

Comment: You should take a look to `real_escape_string`

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $registerUser)) {
    <script>window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com/path/to/account.php";</script>
  } else {
    echo "<script>alert('error while registering you...');</script>";
}
```