# Auto login after signup just doesnt seem to work, redirects to the last user account that has logged in instead.

Tags: php

I'm new to programming in general and want to create a signup form where the user should be auto logged in. However instead of getting directed to their user account, the account details of the previous logged in user shows up instead. Furthermore, when trying to display the UserID in the URL, this does not show up. Here is the code for registration:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "php/config/database.php";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $FirstName  = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $Surname    = $_POST['Surname'];
    $Email      = $_POST['Email'];
    $dbPassword = $_POST['Password'];


    // Check if data exists already in the database
    if (empty($FirstName) || empty($Surname) || empty($Email) || empty($dbPassword)) {
        echo "sorry no rmpty fields";
    }


    $exists  = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Email FROM Users WHERE Email = '$Email'");
    $row     = mysqli_fetch_array($exists);
    $dbEmail = $row['Email'];
    if ($Email == $dbEmail) {
        die("Username already taken.");
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Users(FirstName,Surname,Email,Password)VALUES('$FirstName','$Surname','$Email','$dbPassword')";
        $sqlUserID  = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE UserID = '$UserID'");
        $_SESSION['UserID'] = $dbUserID;
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (!$res) {
            die("Query Failed!" . mysqli_error($conn));

        } else {
            $query  = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $getRow = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            $dbUserID = $getRow['UserID'];
            $dbPassword = $getRow['Password'];


            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                $UserID   = $dbUserID;
                header("Location: account?UserID=".$UserID);
            } else {
                echo "Error! There was a problem registering you!";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>background</title>
 </head>
  <body>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for login:

```
 <?php
 session_start();  

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        include("php/config/database.php"); 
        $Email =$_POST['Email'];
        $dbPassword =$_POST['Password']);
if(empty($Email) || empty($Password))
    {
      echo "sorry no rmpty fields";
    }
    else
    {

        $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $Email);
        $dbPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $dbPassword);

        $dbPassword = md5($dbPassword);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email='$Email' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $UserID = $row['UserID'];
        $dbpass = $row['Password'];

        if($dbPassword == $dbpass) {
            $_SESSION['Email'] = $Email;
            $_SESSION['UserID'] = $UserID;
            header("Location: account.php");
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "You didn't enter the correct details!";
        }

    } 


  }    
?>




<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>background</title>




        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

     <script src="js/index.js"></script>


  </head>

  <body>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <div class="box">
    <h1 id="logintoregister">
      Login
    </h1>
    <div class="group show">
      <input class="inputMaterial" type="text" name="FirstName" />
      <label>First Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="group show">
      <input class="inputMaterial" type="text" name="Surname" />
      <label>Surname</label>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <input class="inputMaterial" type="email" name="Email" />
      <label>Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <input class="inputMaterial" type="password" id="password"
      name="Password" /> <label>Password</label>
    </div>
    <div class="group show">
      <input class="inputMaterial" type="password" id=
      "confirm_password" /> <label>Confirm Password</label>
    </div>



    <button id="buttonlogintoregister" type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
    <p id="plogintoregister">
      By registering, You accept all terms and conditons
    </p>
    <p id="textchange" onclick="register()">
      Sign Up
    </p>
  </div>
</form>


      <!-- Related demos -->




 <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

     <script src="js/index.js"></script>







</body>
</html>
```

Comment: seems pretty close to your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109559/want-to-direct-user-to-their-account-after-sign-up

Comment: and I hope you don't plan on going live with this.

Comment: Given the SQL injection vulnerability, technically you're letting users login as anybody they want.  More to the point, where do you ever define `$UserID`?  You're using it in a `SELECT` query, but never defined it.  Logically, exactly what do you expect to get from this query?:  `"SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE UserID = '$UserID'"`

Answer (score 0):

This line of code simply makes no sense:

```
$sqlUserID  = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE UserID = '$UserID'");
```

1. You're trying to select a value that you claim to *already have*, so what exactly are you selecting?
2. You *don't* have that value, because `$UserID` is never defined.  So at best you're doing this:

   `$sqlUserID  = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE UserID = ''");`

Which, I assume, will not find any records.  So, at best, assuming none of the other logical errors in your code produce runtime breaking errors, you're doing this:

```
header("Location: account?UserID=".$UserID);
```

Which would be evaluated to:

```
"Location: account?UserID="
```